# How to trigger a modal view with Highcharts, when zoom is also enabled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

I have a webpage that displays a Highcharts chart that has zoom type 'x' enabled.  The chart div is wrapped in a container div, like:

```
<div class='chart-container'>
  <div id='chart_0' class='chart'></div>
</div>
```

There is also an event handler attached to the "mouseup" event on the chart-container that switches the chart to a modal view by toggling the modalChart css class defined as:

```
.modalChart {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: 999999;
}

.chart {
  height: 300px;
}

.modalChart .chart {
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: none;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
```

The event handler is defined as:

```
$("body").on("mouseup", ".chart-container", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass "modalChart"
    $(".chart", this).highcharts().reflow()
});
```

The problem I'm having is that the mouseup event on the "chart-container" fires before the setExtremes event fires on the x-axis when zoom is occurring.  So, the modal view is toggled every time the user uses the zoom functionality.  How do I stop this from happening?  I want the user to be able to zoom, without toggling the modal view, and be able to click on the chart to toggle the modal view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of course is that the "mouseup" event on the "chart-container" fires first and the modal view is toggled even when the user is zooming.  To prevent this, we need to delay the modal toggle and cancel it if necessary.  A solution is to delay the modal toggle using setTimeout (associated with a global variable), and then clearTimeout in the appropriate place when using the zoom functionality.

I changed the event handler on the "chart-container" class to:

```
$("body").on("mouseup", ".chart-container", function(){
chart = this
Application.modalTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
    $(chart).toggleClass "modalChart";
    $(".chart", chart).highcharts().reflow();
}, 100)
});
```

and then in the setExtremes event for the xAxis on the chart cancel the setTimeout with:

```
xAxis: {
  events: {
    setExtremes: function(){
      if (Application.modalTimeout)
      {
         return clearTimeout(vm.Analysis.modalTimeout);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I also had to add the clearTimeout functionality to the legendItemClick event for the different chart types in plotOptions.